# what is going wrong in Minimum size subarray sum end condition

Tags: python, algorithm, logic, sliding-window

**Problem**

Given an array of positive integers `nums` and a positive integer `target`, return minimal length of subarray whose
sum is greater than or equal to target. If there is no such subarray, return 0 instead.

Link to the problem: [209. Minimum size subarray sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-size-subarray-sum)

Some examples:

```
nums = [2,3,1,2,4,3] target = 7 output = 2 
nums = [1,4,4] target = 4 output = 1 
nums = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] target = 11 output = 0
```

**My thought process**

```
class Solution(object):
    def minSubArrayLen(self, target, nums):
        i,j,sumSoFar=0,0,0
        N = len(nums)
        if N == 0:
            return 0
        min_len=float('inf')
        while j < N:
            if sumSoFar >= target:
                min_len = min(j-i, min_len)
                sumSoFar-=nums[i]
                i+=1
            else: #sumSoFar is less than target
                sumSoFar+=nums[j]
                j+=1
        if min_len == float('inf'):
            return 0
        return min_len
```

**Issue**

While trying to solve by hand in the first case (`nums = [2,3,1,2,4,3]`, `target = 7`),
I reach `j=6` before I can check for `[3,4]` as a possible solution because `j == N/6`. Also I feel like
when I go to the `if` condition I add `nums[j]` two times (at `j=3`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you initialize `i` and `j`?

Comment: well this is just at thought process but in code id initialize i and j and min len and sumsofar all above the while loop.

Comment: I also meant with which value do you initialize them.

Comment: i=0,j=0, min_len = float("inf"), sumsofar=0 

thats how i am thinking

Comment: Please provide the necessary code that will reproduce the problem when we run it. It should be runnable.

Comment: Your thinking seems good, but you must allow the process to continue after j has reached N; didn't test yet, but I think changing the loop condition to `while j < N or sumSoFar >= target:` should do it.

Comment: i updated with a runnable code @trincot and @ swifty thank you for the comment, that is a great idea let me run it as well as try it by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is good, but the loop will end when j reaches N, which prevents you from finding a legitimate subarray at the end of nums. Adding `or sumSoFar >= target` to the loop condition will allow the algorithm to continue in that case.

Here's a working solution:

```
from math import inf

class Solution(object):
    def minSubArrayLen(self, target, nums):
        i=0
        j=0
        min_len = inf
        sumSoFar=0

        while j < len(nums) or sumSoFar >= target:
            if sumSoFar >= target:
                min_len = min(min_len, j - i)
                sumSoFar -= nums[i]
                i += 1
            else:  # sumSoFar is less than target
                sumSoFar += nums[j]
                j += 1
        return min_len if min_len != inf else 0
```

Example:
`Solution().minSubArrayLen(7, [2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3]) # 2`